# How to rotate a String, one character at a time?

Tags: java

I am unable to complete the logic of this pattern and I have tried every sort of if-else statement

This is the code I am executing:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class String_pattern_01 {



public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the character in continuation to get the pattern");
        String s=sc.next();
        int d=s.length();
        String s2[]=s.split("");
        for(int i=0;i<=s.length();i++)
        {    
            String x= s.substring(i, d);

            if(i>=1&i<d)
            {
                for(i=1;i<d;i++)
                {String y=x+x.substring(0,i-1);
                System.out.println(y);}
            }
            else
            {

                System.out.println(x);
            }

        }

    }
```

}

Comment: Please remember to take the [tour] and to read up on [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask). Explain what you need to do, describe that in as much detail that someone who has no idea what you're doing, understands what you're doing. Explain and show what you've done, explain how that doesn't match what you expected, and talk about what you already tried in order to fix things. Just a post title and a block of code is unlikely to get people to want to invest their time in helping you find out what's wrong.

Comment: Show and briefly explain what is expected output and why.

Comment: i  have clearly written the expected output. But my code output is coming like this:     "abcde">"bcde">"cde">"de">"e".

Comment: how to concate previous character into forward pattern so that every pattern has same no of characters.

Comment: So you are trying to print all permutations of the string, moving the front letter to the back until you get back to the matching string?  The question definitely could use an explanation of that desired behavior, and the current output.

Comment: You definitely haven't written the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can simply reduce the code to a single `for` loop:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the character in continuation to get the pattern");
    String s = sc.next();

    int d = s.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < d; i++)
    {    
        s = s.substring(1, d) + s.charAt(0);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

**Example Run:** With input of `abcde` this will output:

```
bcdea
cdeab
deabc
eabcd
abcde
```

The loop creates a new `String` every iteration by getting the `String`'s first character using `charAt(0)`, then appending it to the end of a `substring` that skips the first character.

Answer (score 1):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String input = "abcde";

  List<String> asList = input.chars()
    .mapToObj(e -> (char) e)
    .map(String::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

  for (int i = 0; i <= input.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(String.join("", asList));
    Collections.rotate(asList, -1);
  }
}
```

1. Turn input `String` into a `List` where each element of the list is a single character
2. Join the list to one `String` and print it
3. Rotate `List` to the left and repeat

This is (kinda) clear way to do this, the ceremony to turn `String` into `List` is the bigger problem than the actual work, but once we got it it's really clear what this code does.